# Need help getting two questions undeleted/unroombad so I can put a bounty on each of them!

Tags: discussion, support, specific-question, deleted-questions

My currently roombad (and invisible to those without enough reputation) questions"

- [Roughly express how much of our Moon's apparent libration amplitude seen from the Geocenter is due to different effects?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/45366/12102)
- [Why was ISEE-3 "the most cost-effective spacecraft we ever had" in 2014?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/43710/12102)

both sat with no up votes and no comments for six months and so the roomba ate each of them.

I'd like to bring each of these back to life and add a bounty to each.

I've added one vote to undelete on each, I need a few more from other users or some moderator assistance.

Thanks!

Also, asked in the main meta: [With limited remaining brain cells, how can I work in a more roomba-aware way (and not lose track of questions permanently)?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/374755/303080)

Comment: Done! The first was already undeleted.

Comment: @called2voyage thanks! status-completed :-) Now I have to wait for some bounties to free-up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you for everyone's help!

Both questions have been undeleted now, and both have been bountied.

By the way [@ Glorfindel's answer to *With limited remaining brain cells, how can I work in a more roomba-aware way (and not lose track of questions permanently)?*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/374822/303080) links to a very helpful SEDE page where I can now "see into the future" with a list of questions that will likely be roombad in the future.

Comment: Very useful SEDE query indeed!

Answer (score 3):

This automatic deletion of good questions are a pain across the Stack Exchange websites. I've posted this feature request on Meta.SE: [Decrease the required view count to prevent Roomba deletion when score = 0 on smaller sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/355097/178179).

Comment: I’ve just upvoted that question and hope others take a look and consider upvoting as well. Thanks!